# How to connect to Windows XP Embedded and Windows 7(in domain)

Tags: windows-7, networking, debug, windows-xp-embedded

I have annoying problem. I would like to connect and see network drives (for purpose of remote debugging) to computer with Windows XP Embedded, Service pack 2. Client computer is Windows 7, service pack 1.

But Win7 PC is located in company domain, so I am not sure if this is not problem. Unfortunatelly, I can't log off domain and go to workgroup, because I would lost all connections to internet and servers. Also I can't connect XPE to domain, because I don't have rights to do it and it is against company politics.

Here are some facts about current state:

1. I can ping one computer to another without problems.
2. Computers are connected directly via crossover lan cable, no router or switch
3. Computer with Windows 7 has two network cards - first is going to company network, second is connected to XP Embedded PC.
4. Both computers are in the same network - they have set IP adress and subnet mask. Default gateway and DNS server fields are empty.
5. I can connect from XPE to Win7 and see (and access) shared folders without any problems, but not backwards from Win7 to XPE.
6. All services on XPE are running : (OM+ Event System (for WZC issues) , Computer Browser , DHCP Client , DNS Client , Network Connections , Network Location Awareness , Remote Procedure Call (RPC) , Server , TCP/IP Netbios helper , Workstation)
7. Every time I try to connect from Win7 to XPE it asks me for user name and password. I am sure that both are correct (I use them for regurally loging into XPE), but it always wants to connect via some domain. This I want to avoid, because XPE isn't in any domain.

Thank you guys. If you have any suggestions how to solve this I will be very pleased. :-) Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

I had setted folders in "advanced sharing" and it causes probably troubles. When I simply shared folders (right slick on folder -> Sharing -> Network sharing and security) and overrides all warnings about security and so on, it simply started.

So, the simplest solutions work the best. :-) Have a nice day, I hope it will help someone.